# Issues installing Blender Animation Nodes on v2.79 on my mac

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I downloaded the zip file for the latest version of [Blender Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes). I then went to Blender's "file -> "user preferences" menu, pressed "install add-on from file" and selected the unopened zip file. I can't seem to find the addon on the list now, and the addon is not showing up in the node editor. Did I do something wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to download it from here: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.0

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded Animation Nodes for Blender 2.79 on my Mac as well. What is the .zip name? This is the one I used.
[image: Filename]
[image: Installed]
After I clicked "Install Add-on from File." it immediately showed up in my list of add-ons. Then I just enabled it.

[This](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.0) is where I downloaded it from.

Comment: Did you download the file called "animation_nodes_v2_0_macos_alternative1.zip" ?

Comment: @BriannaSinger No, I downloaded https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/download/v2.0/animation_nodes_v2_0_macos.zip